# assigning index to a matrix inside for-loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a large data set 200 rows and 5 columns in a .CSV fromat. 
here is part of data set:

```
 4.1    1.2 47.3    10954   51
 3.4    1.5 0.5 1   5316
 0.3    30.1    1.2 10  875
 0.2    0.4 119 0   0
   0    52.6    0.1 0   3.1
   0    0.3 880 0   0
   0    0.1 148 180 0
   0    0.1 490.2   0   0.4
   0    1.1 0.2 0.6 0.9
   0    0   0   0   0
```

I want to write a code to read each 10 rows separately and store it in a matrix(10 by 5) using for-loop. So at the end I have 20 matrices each (10*5). This is the command line:

```
all.data   <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\myarray.csv",header=FALSE)#read whole data
for (k in 1:20){   
data_temp.k <- array(NA, dim=c(10,5))
  for( i in 1:10 ){
    for( j in 1:5 ) {
        data_temp.k[i,j] <- all.data[(k-1)*10:k*10,j]
    }
  }
}
write.csv(data_temp.k,"mymatrix.k")
```

I know the problem is somehow related to "k" and its dual function here as both matrix index and counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a loop for this, use row indexing :

```
## Sample data
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=200,ncol=5)
## Generate indices to keep
indices <- seq(1,nrow(m), by=10)
## Subset matrix rows
m[indices,]
```

Comment: I like your answer but as I mentioned I need index number to be considered for each matrix. So at the end I can have m.1, m.2, ..., m.20 which each of these matrices stores one chunk of the original matrix.

Answer (score 2):

This probably doesn't add much other than being a nice demonstration of how you can use `array`s and `aperm` to split a mtrix into chunks and reshape, all using `base` R vectorised functions. You can always apply functions to each dimension of an array using `apply`.

```
#  Sample data
m <- matrix( 1:16 , 4 , 4 )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
#[3,]    3    7   11   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   16

# Use array() to turn into arrays and aperm() to transpose the 3D array t0 the result you expect
out <- aperm( array( t(m) , c(4,2,2) ) , c(2,1,3) )
#, , 1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14

#, , 2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    7   11   15
#[2,]    4    8   12   16
```

You can apply functions over the third dimension, e.g. using 'apply'

```
#  Sum all the elements in each of the third dimension of your arrays
apply( out , 3 , sum )
#[1] 60 76
```

Comment: This is cool but at the end of the day I want to have for example 20 different matrices in this format: Out.1 , Out.2, ..., Out.3 with different index which each one is one chunk of the original matrix.

Comment: @user2607526 I am compelled to ask... *why*? Almost always it is better to have 20 matrices residing in a single list (or an array) which you can operate on rather freely (once you know how) than cluttering up your workspace with 20 objects. What do you want to *do with them*?

Comment: @ SimonO101; I want to use another forr-loop to read each of them and convert them to netcdf format. That's why I need them to have index then I can recall them in another for-loop. Do you know a better way to recall them?

Comment: @user2607526 If you put them all in a list, you can call them by their position in the list rather than by name (which is sort of inefficient)...it would also then be very easy to use something like `lapply` to do your conversion instead of another loop.

Comment: Sure. I like `for` loops for writing files out, because I think of `for` loops as being for the situation where you expect a side effect rather than a return value (the side effect is the file being written to disk). So if you happen to have an array like above... `for( i in 1:dim(out)[3]){ netcdf( out[,,i] , .... ) }` so `out[,,i]` will refer to each of the matrices (and `netcdf` is your file writing function that I am not familliar with.

Answer (score 0):

If, though, you insist on using a `for` loop, you can -at least- use only one and not three nested loops.

You don't need `j` because you want to keep all columns in each matrix. E.g. `mat[1,]` selects all columns and row 1; you don't need to `mat[1,1:ncol(mat)]`.

Also, the way you use `i` is unneccessary, because you subset more than one row (using `k-1 * 10` etc) to pass to row `i` every time.

Finally, if you're trying to save each of the 20 matrices, you might need `paste`.

This should work (not tested):

```
for(k in 1:20)
 {
  data_temp.k <- all.data[((k-1)*10):(k*10),]

  write.csv(data_temp.k, paste("mymatrix", k, sep = ".")
 }
```